# Video won't play when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click on the red play the video starts playing right away. You can hear the music and everything.

[image]

When you click on the blue play the video **doesn't** start playing. The video does not start and there is no music playing.

There's No audio, and there is no music playing after clicking on the blue play. The video **should start playing** right after **clicking on the blue play.** That's exactly how it works on the red play.

[image]

Clicking on the Blue play should work exactly the same as clicking on the Red play.

After clicking on the **Red** play, the video starts playing right away.

After clicking on the **Blue** play, the video **does not** start playing.

Click **Run** not update to test code.

https://jsitor.com/BOZXPYBWuq

Can someone see if they are able to figure this out.

How would I be able to get the **2nd** video to start playing when it is clicked on?

It should work the **same** as clicking on the **Red** play.

In the code, Both the Red & Blue play use `.thePlay` as a class.

What would need to be **adjusted** or **changed** in the code for it to be working as it should?

**This is The Flow of It:**

For some reason it is only allowing the **1st** `.thePlay` class to play on click, the **2nd** `.thePlay` video class doesn't start when you click on it. Meaning, the video **doesn't** start playing.

**It goes from here:**

```
function play() {
   player.playVideo();
 }
 return {
   addPlayer,
   play
 };
}());
```

**To Here:**

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 const cover = document.querySelector(".thePlay");
 const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
 const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
 videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
```

**To Here:**

```
(function initCover() {

 function coverClickHandler() {
   videoPlayer.play();
 }

 const cover = document.querySelector(".thePlay");
 cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

**Full Code:**

```
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
 const config = {};

 function show(el) {
   el.classList.remove("hide");
 }

 function hide(el) {
   el.classList.add("hide");
 }

 function hideAll(elements) {
   elements.forEach(hide);
 }

 function showCovers(playButton) {
   const cover = playButton.parentElement;
   cover.classList.add("active");
   show(cover);
 }

 function coverClickHandler(evt) {
   hideAll(config.containers);
   const cover = evt.currentTarget;
   showCovers(cover);
 }

 function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
   playButtons.forEach(function addEventHandler(playButton) {
     playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
   });
 }

 function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
   const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
   cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
 }

 function init(selectors) {
   config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
   const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
   addClickToButtons(playButtons);
 }

 return {
   addCoverHandler,
   init,
   show
 };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
 const players = [];
 let playerVars = {};
 let player = null;

 const tag = document.createElement("script");
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
 const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


 function onPlayerReady(event) {
   player = event.target;
   player.setVolume(100);

 }

 function addPlayer(video, settings) {
   const playerVarDefaults = {
     host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
     videoId: video.dataset.id
   };
   playerVarDefaults.events = {
     "onReady": onPlayerReady
   };
   playerVars = Object.assign(playerVarDefaults, settings);
   players.push(new YT.Player(video, playerVars));
 }

 function play() {
   player.playVideo();
 }
 return {
   addPlayer,
   play
 };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
 const defaults = {
   height: 600,
   width: 360
 };
 defaults.playerVars = {
   controls: 1,
   disablekb: 1,
   enablejsapi: 1,
   fs: 0,
   iv_load_policy: 3,
   rel: 0
 };

 function show(el) {
   el.classList.remove("hide");
 }

 function createPlayerOptions(settings) {
   function paramInOptions(opts, param) {
     if (settings[param] !== undefined) {
       opts[param] = settings[param];
       delete settings[param];
     }
     return opts;
   }

   const optionParams = ["width", "height", "videoid", "host"];
   const preferred = optionParams.reduce(paramInOptions, {});
   const playerOptions = Object.assign({}, defaults, preferred);
   // settings should now only consist of playerVars
   const playerVars = Object.assign({}, defaults.playerVars, settings);
   playerOptions.playerVars = playerVars;
   return playerOptions;
 }

 function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
   const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
   const playerOptions = createPlayerOptions(settings);
   return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
 }

 function createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings) {
   return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
     const cover = evt.currentTarget;
     const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
     show(wrapper);
     const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerSettings);
     wrapper.player = player;
   };
 }

 function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerSettings) {
   const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerSettings);
   manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
 }

 return {
   add: addPlayer
 };
}());
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 const cover = document.querySelector(".thePlay");
 const wrapper = cover.parentElement;
 const frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
 videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);

 managePlayer.add(".playa", {
   height: 207,
   start: 4,
   width: 277
 });
 managePlayer.add(".playb", {
   height: 207,
   width: 277
 });
 manageCover.init({
   container: ".container",
   playButton: ".thePlay"
 });
}
(function initCover() {

 function coverClickHandler() {
   videoPlayer.play();
 }

 const cover = document.querySelector(".thePlay");
 cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <svg class="playa thePlay" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="qe5WF4qCSkQ"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end container -->
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <svg class="playb thePlay " width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
      M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </svg>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="2VwsvrPFr9w"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I run the example on jsitor and click the red button it plays the video.  If I re-run the example and this time click the blue button it plays a video.  Isn't this the expected behavior?  If so, then I cannot reproduce your issue...

Comment: The video on the blue play Does Not start playing right away, the same as the red. You hear audio after you click on the blue play?

Comment: There's No audio, and there is no music playing after clicking on the blue play. The video should start playing right after clicking on the blue play. That's exactly how it works on the red play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code is really too long i can't look at all parts of it but as you referred at the post that the red button is the first and blue is the second i guess that's done because you're used `querySelector` to select the buttons but unfortunately `querySelector` return just the first element you need to use `querySelectorAll` and make a loop something like

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 const cover = document.querySelectorAll(".thePlay");
 for(let i of cover) {
   let wrapper = i.parentElement,
   frameContainer = wrapper.querySelector(".video");
   videoPlayer.addPlayer(frameContainer);
  } 
}
```

i hope that's helpful

Comment: I tried that and it's not working in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to lie in this function (I added the console.log for debugging purposes):

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const cover = document.querySelector(".thePlay");console.log(cover);
```

Although it does get called twice, once for each of the two videos getting loaded, it starts by setting the varable cover to the **first** video so that gets set up to run immediately twice. The second video is not selected.

You need to look through the logic so you can pick up the correct video and initialise that to start playing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236556/discussion-on-answer-by-a-haworth-video-wont-play-when-clicked).

Comment: I added my attempts in the chat discussion because the text won't fit in here.

Comment: How do I fix it, it's still not working properly?

Comment: Are you still helping me to figure this out? It's still not working, I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Hi, I really don't think I can help much more. My suggestion would be that you step through the code line by line making sure you understand exactly what the code is doing (e.g. the difference between querySelector and querySelectorAll). I'm afraid coding is all about extreme accuracy.